# Extract value from a MySQL table

Tags: php

I am learning PHP and MySQL.  I have a table (members) that has 2 columns: username and university. Using PHP, I want to echo the university of a given user.  The following query is not working:

```
$university = queryMysql("SELECT university FROM members WHERE username='$user'");
echo $university;
```

The function queryMysql does this:

```
function queryMysql($query)
{
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
     return $result;
}
```

Comment: So what result do you get back from the `queryMysql()` function? Is it an array?

Comment: This, which is clearly not correct:  Resource id #10

Comment: Does your `queryMysql()` use MySQL, MySQLi, PDO?

Comment: You should include the definition for your `queryMysql()` function. What you're getting back is a pointer to the query's result, which needs to be used to get each row back.

Comment: You need to use the `$result` with [`mysql_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php). Note the big honking pink box at the top of the manual page telling you *not* to use the `mysql_` functions anymore. You should (need) to learn MySQLi and/or PDO instead.

Comment: Ok, i will convert it to mysqli.  The result will always be one university.  How can I make the output echo the university name rather than an array.  Right now it is echoing this:
Array ( [0] => stanford).  I would like it to just echo 'stanford'

Comment: Do you know how to access the first item in a numerically indexed array?

Comment: No.  This is my first week of learning coding.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing (Note the `42` example.)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
$university = queryMysql("SELECT university FROM members WHERE username='".$user."'");
$row = mysql_fetch_row($university);
print_r($row);
```

Comment: Ok, i will convert it to mysqli. The result will always be one university. How can I make the output echo the university name rather than an array. Right now it is echoing this: Array ( [0] => stanford). I would like it to just echo 'stanford'

Comment: If you're sure that there's only one result echo it like this `echo $row[0];`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that queryMysql is a wrapper for mysql_query, then yes it would return a resource, not the data directly. If it returns Boolean false then the query was unsuccessful. Otherwise, call mysql_fetch_assoc($university) which should return you an associative array which contains the result of the query.
Ideally you shouldn't use the MySQL extension anymore (especially if your query is being built from a post request or other form of potentially untrusted data. If you haven't escaped it correctly you'll be open to SQL injection, which could allow malicious users to collect or tamper with data to which they should not have access. Use PDO instead.

Comment: Thanks.  How can I get an output of a value rather than an array.  The output will always be just one university.  Right now it is echoing this:
Array ( [0] => stanford )
I would like it to echo just 'stanford'

Comment: Do something like: echo result[0]; to echo the contents of element 0. In the case of associative arrays you'd echo the key name like: echo result['university']. print_arr will output all the data in the array.

Comment: He needs to fetch the result first. He's only returning the query object.